# Скачивание из Dropbox API v2 Java SDK

Tags: java, android, dropbox

Кто-нибудь может объяснить как скачать текстовый файл из `Dropbox API v2`.
В интернете в основном на устаревшую версию `Dropbox API v1`.
На `Dropbox` зарегистрирован; `App key`, `App secret` и `Generated access token` имеется.

Comment: возьмите доки по Api на официальном сайте, там все есть https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/java#documentation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578034/how-to-download-file-with-new-dropbox-api